# php login form not working correctly when i add username functionality

Tags: php, mysql

I created a login form in PHP and now I have a password, email and username stored in the database  when I use this query in my database  form works correctly

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'  AND password='$password' ";
```

But when I add username functionality too it does not work correctly
this is my username code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$email' or email = '$email'  AND password='$password' ";
```

Basically what happens is this, when I add username functionality when I try to login with username and type any password it logs in but when I try with email and try any password it says invalid and it works only with correct password now I want it to work correctly with username too

this is my whole code

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['is_login'])) {

   # code...

if (isset($_POST['btn_login'])) {
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($_POST['email'])); 
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,md5(trim($_POST['password'])));

 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$email' or email = '$email'  AND password='$password' ";

 $fire = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 if ($fire) {
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire) == 1) {


  $_SESSION['is_login'] = 'true';
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

  header("Location: dashboard");

}else{
  $errorfname= '<p style="color:#cc0000;">invalid username or password</p>';
}
}
}
}else{
  header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Does you username also contain email values

Comment: yes both email and username have same input field @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: This might be an issue of operator precedence. Try `WHERE (username='$email' or email = '$email')  AND password...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use parentheses properly. Put parentheses `( .. )` around `OR` condition checking.

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$email' or email = '$email')  
                                      AND password='$password' ";
```

From [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html):

```
AND, &&
XOR
OR, ||
```

`AND` takes higher precedence than `OR`. So, basically without using parentheses, `email = '$email' AND password='$password'` would have executed first. Now this may return `false` if password is incorrect. But then, `username='$email'` will be executed, and it will return `true` if correct email id is used. Now, `true or false = true`. So even with wrong password, but correct email id, anybody could have logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$email' or email = '$email')  AND password='$password' ";
```